# What are the a and b parameters in scipy.stats.johnsonsu?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, finance

I am toying around with fitting a [Johnson SU](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html) distribution to an empirical set of S&P 500 Index returns.  My understanding (disclaimer: not a math guy) is that this distribution incorporates the third and fourth moments (skew & kurtosis).  In addition to `loc` (the mean) and `scale` (the std deviation), `johnsonsu` takes two additional parameters, `a` and `b`.  But the order and specification of these parameters is confusing.

Here's where my confusion stems from: if I pull in returns to SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust (SPY), I get the following empirical stats:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader as dr
r = dr('SPY', 'google', start='2000')['Close'].pct_change().dropna()
mean, var, std, skew, kurt = r.mean(), r.var(0), r.std(0), r.skew(), r.kurt() # ddof = 0
# mean: 0.00027732907268771364
# var: 0.00014416720067485022
# std: 0.012006964673673785
```

Now if I fit a normal distribution to this empirical data, `.fit` is supposed to return the `loc` and `scale` parameters.  (All that is needed for a normal distribution.)  That checks out:

```
import scipy.stats as scs

normmean, normstd = scs.norm.fit(r)
print(np.allclose(normmean, mean))
print(np.allclose(normstd, std))

True
True
```

But it is less clear what is returned by `scs.johnsonsu.fit`:

```
print(scs.johnsonsu.fit(r))
(0.098009661042083682, 1.022060362199493, 0.0013471690867203458, 0.0072653444313926403)
```

These should be the [four parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution) to the distribution: *xi, gamma, delta, lam*.

But I cannot get them to back into the empirical mean, which should be:
[image]

I.e.:

```
def johnsonmean(gamma, xi, delta, lam):
    mean = xi - lam * np.exp(delta ** -2 / 2) * np.sinh(gamma / delta)
    return mean
gamma, xi, delta, lam = scs.johnsonsu.fit(r) # correct order?
print(johnsonmean(gamma, xi, delta, lam))
-inf
```

And

```
mean, var, skew, kurt = scs.johnsonsu.stats(loc=xi, scale=lam, 
                                            a=gamma, b=delta, moments='msvk')
```

gets a bunch of `NaN`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are parameters of the [Johnson SU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution). Remember, what you've got as mean of the sample is not the same as mean of the distribution. Here is expression for the mean value

[image]

And here is expression for variance:

[image]

In your code,   ξ would be `loc`,     λ would be `scale`,   γ would be `a` and δ would be `b`. sinh<sup>-1</sup>(x) is equal to log(x + sqrt(1 + x<sup>2</sup>)).

So check the return of the fit, assign values to all four parameters, and then compute distribution mean and compare with the sample mean. If it works, repeat exercise for variance

UPDATE

I tried your code and proposed check for mean and variance and it worked well, please check below

```
import sys
import math

from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader as dr
import scipy.stats as scs

def read_data():
    return dr('SPY', 'google', start='2000')['Close'].pct_change().dropna()

def johnsonsu_mean(a, b, loc, scale):
    """
    Johnson SU mean according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution
    """
    v = loc - scale * math.exp(0.5 / b**2) * math.sinh(a/b)
    return v

def johnsonsu_var(a, b, loc, scale):
    """
    Johnson SU variance according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution
    """
    t = math.exp(1.0 / b**2)
    v = 0.5*scale**2 * (t - 1.0) * (t * math.cosh(2.0*a/b) + 1.0)
    return v

def johnsonsu_median(a, b, loc, scale):
    """
    Johnson SU median according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution
    """
    v = loc + scale * math.sinh(-a/b)
    return v

def main(r):
    sample_mean, sample_med, sample_var, sample_std, sample_skew, sample_kurt = r.mean(), r.median(), r.var(0), r.std(0), r.skew(), r.kurt()

    a, b, loc, scale = scs.johnsonsu.fit(r) # fit the data and get distribution parameters back

    # distribution mean and variance according to SciPy
    dist_mean = scs.johnsonsu.mean(a, b, loc, scale)
    dist_med  = scs.johnsonsu.median(a, b, loc, scale)
    dist_var  = scs.johnsonsu.var(a, b, loc, scale)

    # distribution mean, var vs sample ones
    print("{0} {1}".format(sample_mean, dist_mean))
    print("{0} {1}".format(sample_med, dist_med))
    print("{0} {1}".format(sample_var, dist_var))
    print("")

    # distribution mean and variance according to Wiki vs SciPy
    print("{0} {1}".format(dist_mean, johnsonsu_mean(a, b, loc, scale)))
    print("{0} {1}".format(dist_var, johnsonsu_var(a, b, loc, scale)))
    print("{0} {1}".format(dist_med, johnsonsu_median(a, b, loc, scale)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = read_data()
    main(r)

    sys.exit(0)
```

And produced output:

```
0.00028012130615107805 0.00021391570000183283  
0.0005697194131890626 0.0006458197694718355    
0.00014415554662672425 0.00015479059187195545  

0.00021391570000183283 0.00021391570000541633  
0.00015479059187195545 0.00015479059186527505  
0.0006458197694718355 0.0006458197694718355
```